# Change width and height in focus and hover pseudo-class in qtstylesheet

Tags: python, pyqt5, qtstylesheets, qlineedit

how can I change width and height when is hover or focus QLineEdit

Stylesheet in qt designer:

```css
QLineEdit:hover{
    border: 2px solid bule;
}

QLineEdit:focus {
    background-color :#e1e1e1;
    border-radius:4px;
    border : 2px solid red;
}
```

Comment: Width and height of *what*? Of the whole QLineEdit? That doesn't seem a very good idea, as it could create serious problems in layout management and even recursion.

Comment: Yes , of the whole QLineEdit. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

use `enterEvent` and `QPropertyAnimation` to achieve this.

```
def __init__(self):
    self.your_line_edit.enterEvent = self.changeWidth #enter event will be called when cursor is hovered over the widget.

def changeWidth(self, event):
    self.widthAnimation =  QPropertyAnimation(self.your_line_edit, b"minimumWidth")
    self.widthAnimation.setDuration(500)
    self.widthAnimation.setStartValue(200) #Initial width
    self.widthAnimation.setEndValue(500) #Final width
    self.widthAnimation.start()
```

You can use the `leaveEvent` to shrink your line edit after the mouse leaves.